# Save file with file_put_contents in folder

Tags: php, apache

```
file_put_contents('image.jpg',file_get_contents('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg'));
```

Saving the file in current folder is working ok, but if I try

```
file_put_contents('/subfolder/image.jpg',file_get_contents('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg'));
```

I have an error:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in […]

Why does this error occur? How can I save the file in a subfolder?

Comment: Do you have rights to save it in this folder?

Comment: Try removing the leading slash.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Always use full paths and make sure the directory is writable. You can also use `copy` directly with URL

```
$url = 'http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg';
$dir = __DIR__ . "/subfolder"; // Full Path
$name = 'image.jpg';

is_dir($dir) || @mkdir($dir) || die("Can't Create folder");
copy($url, $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name);
```

Comment: When to use file_put_contents in this example code?

Comment: @pal4life you don't need copy can be used on URLs

Answer (score 11):

Try to leave out the first slash:

```
file_put_contents('subfolder/image.jpg',file_get_contents('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg'));
```

Check the access rights if this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You should check if folder exsits and if not create this folder

```
$dir_to_save = "/subfolder/";
if (!is_dir($dir_to_save)) {
  mkdir($dir_to_save);
}
file_put_contents($dir_to_save.'image.jpg',file_get_contents('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg'));
```

also make sure that you want to use **ABSOLUTE_PATH** instead of **RELATIVE**

Answer (score 1):

```html
file_put_contents('../subfolder/image.jpg',file_get_contents('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg'));

add "../" in your string put into the file_put_contents function then it will work fine..
```

Comment: add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = "folder_name".$filename;
```

you can use the above to simply put contents to any file of any folder.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was caused by folder permissions.
when I created my subfolder, the `root` was the owner,
since my php runs with the `apache` user, I needed to update the owner of the folder to be `apache`.

Answer (score 0):

Use FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH

If 'html' is the subfolder where you want to save the file to:

file_put_contents('html/'.$filename.'.ext', $text, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH | FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Answer (score 0):

In MAMP on a Mac, something like this will work:

```
file_put_contents( '/Users/user/Sites/mysite.mamp/wp-content/test-files/delete-this-test.html', '<p>foo</p>' );
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use backslashes:

```
     file_put_contents('images\\'.$filename, base64_decode($imgBase64));
```

or

```
    file_put_contents('K:\\Site\\images\\'.$filename, base64_decode($imgBase64));
```