# Generate png-file with php from dataURI sent through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, svg

I have an svg file that is generating a dataURI-png and that works great. And I want that dataURI to be saved as an image, therefore I try to send the dataURI through ajax to another server that can execute PHP. But I can't get it to work.

This is the code for generating the dataURI (that works)

```
var mySVG    = document.querySelector('svg'),      // Inline SVG element
tgtImage = document.querySelector('.tgtImage');      // Where to draw the result
can      = document.createElement('canvas'), // Not shown on page
ctx      = can.getContext('2d'),
loader   = new Image;                        // Not shown on page

console.log(mySVG);

loader.width  = can.width  = tgtImage.width;
loader.height = can.height = tgtImage.height;
loader.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage( loader, 0, 0, loader.width, loader.height );
    tgtImage.src = can.toDataURL("image/png");
};
```

This is the ajax-code to send it to the external php-server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {id:'testID',datauri: can.toDataURL("image/png")},
    crossDomain: true,
    //dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://urltoscript.php",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

The PHP-code to generate the png

```
$dataUrl = $_REQUEST['datauri'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

list($meta, $content) = explode(',', $dataUrl);
$content = base64_decode($content);
file_put_contents('./tmp-png/'.$id.'.png', $content);
```

The PNG-generation works when manualy inserting the dataURI. But it doesn't work with the ajax function above.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: Can you change `php`?

Comment: Yes. Can change php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`canvas.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob), send image to `php` as a `Blob`, use [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) to read `Blob` at `php` , see [Beyond $_POST, $_GET and $_FILE: Working with Blob in JavaScript and PHP](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/03/beyond-post-and-get-working-with-blob.html)

javascript

```
if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
 Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, "toBlob", {
  value: function (callback, type, quality) {

    var binStr = atob( this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(",")[1] ),
        len = binStr.length,
        arr = new Uint8Array(len);

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
     arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || "image/png"} ) );
  }
 });
}

can.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // to receive `echo`ed file from `php` as `Blob`
  // request.responseType = "blob";
  request.open("POST", "readBlobInput.php", true);
  request.setRequestHeader("x-file-name", "filename");
  request.onload = function() {
    // `this.response` : `Blob` `echo`ed from `php`
    // console.log(this.response)
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
  request.send(blob)
});
```

readBlobInput.php

```
<?php
// the Blob will be in the input stream, so we use php://input
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
// choose a filename, use request header
$tmpFilename = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FILE_NAME"];
// http://stackoverflow.com/q/541430/
$folder = __DIR__ . "/tmp-png"; 
// http://stackoverflow.com/q/17213403/
is_dir($folder) || @mkdir($folder) || die("Can't Create folder");
// put contents of file in folder
file_put_contents($folder . "/" . $tmpFilename, $input);
// get MIME type of file
$mime = mime_content_type($folder . "/" . $tmpFilename);
$type = explode("/", $mime);
// set MIME type at file
$filename = $tmpFilename . "." . $type[1];
// rename file including MIME type
rename($folder . "/" . $tmpFilename, $folder . "/" . $filename);
// to echo file 
// header("Content-Type: " . $type); 
// echo file_get_contents($newName);
echo $filename . " created";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried it since someone else har taken over the project for know. I've forwarded this to them and I'll get back here if I try it!

Comment: @AlbertJohansson See updated post. Included `request.setRequestHeader("x-file-name", "filename");` at `javascript` portion

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataUrl = $_REQUEST['datauri'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

list($meta, $content) = explode(',', $dataUrl);

$content = str_replace(".", "", $content); // some android browsers will return a data64 that may not be accurate without this without this.

$content = base64_decode($content);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($content);

imagepng($image, './tmp-png/'.$id.'.png', 90); // Third parameter is optional. Just placed it incase you want to save storage space...
```