# Html File Save - How to overcome the 2K limit on GET. (Note POST does not work)

Tags: javascript, php, html, save

I am saving a file constructed in javascript to the local internet downloads directory.

This works:

javascript

```
var filename = "mysave.txt"
var contents = "xyz";
document.location = "htmlsave.php?filename=" + filename + "&contents=" + contents;
```

htmlsave.php:

```
if(!isset($_GET)) {
    exit(0);
}
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$contents = $_GET['contents'];

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($contents));
header("Connection: close");
echo $contents;
```

This does not:

javascript:

```
var i;
var filename = "mysave.txt"
var contents = "";
for(i=0, contents = "";i<10000;i++){
    contents += "x";
}
document.location = "htmlsave.php?filename=" + filename + "&contents=" + contents;
```

This obviously does not work due to the 2K limit on the url.

The error is:

```
Request-URI Too Long
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
```

Obviously you need to use POST, but how do you do it with POST? How do you do the 'document.location =' bit with POST data? You cannot do an ajax POST, (see below), I have tried it and it does not work.

The failed POST method:

javascript:

```
var filename = "mysave.txt"
var contents = "";
for(i=0, contents = "";i<10000;i++){
    contents += "x";
}
dataARR = {
    filename: filename,
    contents: contents
};
var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(dataARR);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // This for array
    url: "htmlsave.php",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: false, // This needs to be true for other people
    data: { myJson: dataJSON },

    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

htmlsave.php

```
if(!isset($_POST) || !isset($_POST['myJson'])) {
    exit(0);
}
$dataTotal = json_decode($_POST['myJson'], true);
$filename = $dataTotal['filename'];
$contents = $dataTotal['contents'];

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($contents));
header("Connection: close");
echo $contents;
```

So what can I do to save files greater than 2K?

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to save a javascript generated file, greater than 2K, to the client's internet download directory.

Comment: You can achieve this without using `php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php` is not necessary to create, prompt user to save file created at `javascript`. You can use `<a>` element with `download` attribute set to `filename`, `href` set to `objectURL` of `Blob` containing file data to initiate prompt for user to save file.

If you want to use `php` you can utilize `php://input`, `file_get_contents()`, `echo` `POST`ed `Blob` or `File` object.

```js
var i;
var filename = "mysave.txt"
var contents = "";
for(i=0, contents = "";i<10000;i++){
    contents += "x";
}

var data = new Blob([contents], {type:"text/plain"});
var file = URL.createObjectURL(data);
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = filename;
a.href = file;
a.click();
```

---

Using `file_ge_contents()`, `php://input`

javascript

```
var i;
var filename = "mysave.txt"
var contents = "";
for(i=0, contents = "";i<10000;i++){
    contents += "x";
}

var data = new Blob([contents], {type:"text/plain"});

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/path/to/server");
request.setRequestHeader("x-file-name", filename);
request.reponseType = "blob";
request.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.response); // `echo`ed file
};
request.send(data);
```

php

```
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

See also [Generate png-file with php from dataURI sent through ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236047/generate-png-file-with-php-from-datauri-sent-through-ajax) ; though note `request.setRequestHeader("x-file-name", filename);` should have been included at `javascript` portion of Answer for `$tmpFilename = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FILE_NAME"];` at `php`

Comment: This looks good, but it is directing me to the App Store. First it asks, 'Do you want to allow this website to open an application on your computer'? Then it directs me to the App Store looking for something that can read Blobs.

Comment: @Rewind _"This looks good, but it is directing me to the App Store. First it asks, 'Do you want to allow this website to open an application on your computer'? Then it directs me to the App Store looking for something that can read Blobs."_ Interesting. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 is where it asks for the App Store. Firefox does not like your method at all, it just does nothing. On Chrome it works perfectly.

Comment: Out of interest, how do you implement your php method?

Comment: Version for firefox, where user can click `<a>` element http://plnkr.co/edit/siwYwGe5e8Pf1hH4atKq?p=preview. If you `POST` `Blob` or `File` object you should be able to use `echo file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: Your plnkr works on Chrome, Edge, Firefox. It only does not work on IE 11. As for your php, I am not great at php, would it be possible to add that to the end of your answer above? I am not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Rewind See updated post. Note, have not tried ie in some time